# SQL CASE fails when using left() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL `CASE` statement which checked that a value contains a comma and then performs the `left` and `charindex` function on it.

However the query fails because it looks like its still trying to execute the `left()` function on it.

```
select 
   case 
      when '12560' like '%,%' 
        then left('12560',charindex(',', '12560', 0) - 1) 
        else '12560'  
   end
```

I basically may or may not have a comma in the parameter and therefore may or may not want to do a left on it.

Can this be done in a single case statement? If not I will have to write function to do this with an IF statement.

The error is:

> Msg 536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the left function.

Thanks

Comment: Is `'12560'` a column or just a string?

Comment: ... because a constant expression `charindex(',','12560',0)` is evaluated (*Constant Folding*) at the start of the batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `ISNULL()` statement around the `CHARINDEX`.

Example:

```sql
select 
   case 
      when '12560' like '%,%' 
        then left('12560',ISNULL(charindex(',', '12560', 0),1) - 1) 
        else '12560'  
   end
```

[SQLFiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f758)

**EDIT**

For the sake of completeness, you could wrap this in a variable and get the same result (without the ISNULL), due to the *constant folding* that Alex mentioned in the comments:

```sql
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(5) = '12560'
select 
   case 
      when @str like '%,%' 
        then left(@str,charindex(',', @str, 0) - 1) 
        else @str 
   end
```

Comment: or `charindex(',', '12560,', 0)`